# QISKit warrning on marshmallow

Tags: programming, qiskit

I have updated qiskit module but unfortunately, it doesn't work it says

```
C:\Users\Aman\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32
\lib\site-packages\marshmallow\schema.py:364: 
ChangedInMarshmallow3Warning: strict=False is not recommended. 

In marshmallow 3.0, schemas will always be strict. See 
https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/upgrading.html
#schemas-are-always-strict ChangedInMarshmallow3Warning
```

What shall I do?

Answer (score 3):

This is a Just a Python warning about deprecated usage. It will be fixed in the [next release](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-terra/pull/1652). It should not prevent you from upgrading Qiskit or writing any code today.

Comment: I used 'pip install -U qiskit' then everything goes wrong. And I can't run my code!!!!

Comment: Can you you post your code or any other errors you're seeing?

Comment: I found it. it is just the plot_histogram function doesn't work. When I change it to the print it works fine!! Thank You!!